# Cards com conteúdo menor quebrando

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou utilizando `Bootstrap 4` para montar uma pagina, e na hora de fazer uns cards eles estão ficando maior ou menor que os outros, mesmo eles utilizando a mesma classe `col-sm-4`. Ele esta quebrando porque o conteúdo deles é menor. minha duvida é como deixar esses cards do mesmo tamanho independente do conteúdo deles, e também em como colocar o `h2` deles no meio, pois a classe `text-center` só funcionou no `p`

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box-shadow-full">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- icone -->
          <h2>1</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat dolor fuga neque obcaecati reiciendis doloribus ipsa dicta itaque aperiam quasi vero, quo quam eum enim repellendus magnam iusto iure perferendis.,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box-shadow-full">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- icone -->
          <h2>2</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, facere doloribus. Repudiandae iste deserunt odio ullam vitae voluptate nihil itaque ex culpa ab, quos blanditiis fugiat magni sequi debitis fuga?,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box-shadow-full">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- icone -->
          <h2>3</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam suscipit reiciendis nesciunt tenetur excepturi accusantium maiores fugit, illo  possimus sunt nihil. Fugiat corporis quod id nemo aliquam?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box-shadow-full">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- icone -->
          <h2>4</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ab debitis saepe ad dicta? Quis maxime nemo sapiente fugit, quo ratione ad perferendis quaerat, ipsa dolore, dolor molestiae iusto officia?.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box-shadow-full">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- icone -->
          <h2>5</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut tempore sunt natus ab perspiciatis ea beatae commodi optio voluptas porro vero aspernatur debitis, corrupti, libero eius doloremque quae repellendus. Alias!,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box-shadow-full">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- icone -->
          <h2>6</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qu.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: Cards quebrando]

Comment: Existem várias técnicas para criar cards de mesma altura. Poste o código que você está usando para analisarmos.

Comment: @Maujor opa, falha minha em esquecer o código, Já editei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara já existe nativamente no Bootstrap 4 uma forma de "alinhar" a altura dos cards, e é com um `Card Group` como vc pode ver aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois vc pode usar outras classes nativas como a `border` e a `m-n°` para ajustar o espaçamento entro eles etc.

Outra coisa é que o `text-center` funciona perfeitamente na tag `Hn°` como vc pode ver no exemplo abaixo. Outra coisa é que o BS também tem uma classe de `box-shadow` a partir da **versão 4.1** como vc pode consultar aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/shadows/

***Repare que nem existe CSS no exemplo, foitudo com as classes do BS mesmo...***

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="card-group col-12">
   <div class="card m-3 border shadow-sm">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <h2 class="text-center">meu h2</h2>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
      This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card m-3 border shadow-sm">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <h2 class="text-center">meu h2</h2>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus similique quibusdam quasi repellendus consequatur tenetur molestias quo perferendis quam iure. additional content.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card m-3 border shadow-sm">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <h2 class="text-center">meu h2</h2>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natution.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, aconselho você a não ficar preso a bootstrap sempre, e aprender a codificar seu próprio CSS pra quando aparecer esse tipo de problema e você não ficar engessado pra fazer algo.

No h2 basta você fazer:

```
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Na parte dos cards, você pode colocar assim:

```
.container > .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```